# R integration with Tableau

Tags: r, integration, tableau-api

I am facing difficulty in integrating R with Tableau. 
Initially when I created calculated field it was asking for Rserve package in R and was not alowing to drag field to worksheet. I have installed this package but still it shows error saying
 "Error occurred while communicating with the Resrve service.Tableau i unable to connect to the service.Verify that server is running and that you have access privileges"

Any inputs. Thank you

Comment: Have you started RServe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start Rserve. If you successfully install Rserve package, simply run this (on RGui, RStudio or wherever you run R scripts)

```
> library(Rserve)
> Rserve()
```

You can test your connection to RServe on Tableau, on Help, Settings and Performance, Manage R Connection.

Comment: Relate to this http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/r-implementation-notes

Comment: Thanks a lot.It's working fine now. After running above commands I edited connection in the same place you have given.

Answer (score 1):

As of Tableau 9, you can use `*.rdata` files with Tableau. Tableau 9 will read the first item stored in the `*.rdata` file. Just open an `*.rdata` file under `"Statistical Files"` in the Tableau intro screen.

To do this do:

```
save(myDataframe, "Myfile.rdata")
```

This will save the file with the `dataframe` stored in it. You can save as many items as you want, but Tableau will only read the first. It can read vectors and variables as well if they are in the first item. Note that `rdata` files compress data quite a bit. I recently compressed 900mb to 25mb. However Tableau will still need to decompress it to use it so be careful about memory.